# How to create a 2D grid in webpage?

Tags: javascript, html

How can I create a grid (10X10) in a webpage and allow an user to click any position in the grid and recording the (x,y) position in one-decimal approx such as covering the values 0.0~10.0 or 0.1~9.9?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use a [`<canvas>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Canvas) for the grid, and [attach a `click` event listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener).

Comment: It will be much simpler to write JavaScript code that works in all browsers if you use a library such as [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com).

Answer (score 1):

You can record mouse clicks using the clientX and clientY properties of the mouse event object:

```
document.addEventListener('click', function(event){event.clientX;event.clientY;}, false);
```

The above code is just a demonstration, it isn't even cross browser compatible. `event.clientX` and `event.clientY` hold the mouse coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

### *[demo](http://jsbin.com/uzadoy/edit#javascript,html,live)*

I used the jQuery library.

```
var boxX = 0;
var boxY = 0;
var box = '<div class="box" />'; // define the .box element

for(var i = 0; i<100;i++){       // create 100 boxes
  $('#grid').append(box);
}

$('.box').on('click',function(){
  boxX = $(this).position().left;
  boxY = $(this).position().top;
  $(this).text('X='+ boxX +' , Y='+ boxY);
});
```

Instead of `.position()` (to get the element position from the parent element)
 you can use `.offset()` to get the element offset from window boundaries.